# Will Apple's apps be automatically updated when the OS is upgraded?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-appstore

I have a MacBook Pro from mid-2014 running on Yosemite. If I update the macOS, will the Apple apps  (iTunes, Pages, Numbers, etc.) be automatically updated?

I have also been wondering whether it would be a good idea to upgrade to High Sierra. I am hesitant because the system is running smoothly, and I have seen that people report some problems after upgrading, so I would very much appreciate your thoughts on this matter.

Comment: I would suggest waiting until Mojave is released. No point in taking time to **backup** & upgrade twice.

Comment: *I have seen that people report some problems after upgrading...*  There's no operating system in existence that updates/upgrades perfectly for 100% of the people.  High Sierra is a stable OS now and is worth upgrading.  Contrary to what @JBis advised, an old adage in IT is "never upgrade to a dot zero version."  When Mojave is released it will be 10.14.0

Comment: FYI Flagged as mostly opinion based

Comment: I suggest making a backup (as an ongoing strategy), perform the upgrade and address issues as they arise.

Comment: @Allan Although true, I didn't mean immediately. The OP has survived with outdated/old OS for a while now. I think that the OP can wait a bit more for 10.14.(!0). P.S. (At least with my experience), Mojave is very good even in beta.

Comment: Flagged to close as opinion-based, but the amount of trouble I've had with Sierra & HS, I'd stay where you are for now. See if Mojave is any better :/

Comment: @Tetsujin Problems with sierra too? I had great experience with Sierra. HS sucked. Mojave seems very good.

Comment: I was on Sierra for a whole month, then went back to El Cap. HS was even worse, I've had to dump APFS to get any sense out of it, but since then it's *almost* OK. You can look through my question history for the tales of woe ;-)

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah. The start of APFS was a mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In answer to your question:

> if I update the macOS, will the Apple apps (iTunes, Pages, Numbers, etc.) be automatically updated?

Update from @nohillside:

Updating macOS will not update applications downloaded from the Mac App Store, so you will need to manually update Pages, Numbers etc.

Comment: Updating macOS will not update applications downloaded from the Mac App Store, so you will need to manually update Pages, Numbers etc.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for your correction @nohillside. I apologize for not thoroughly researching before replying.

Comment: Can you update the answer accordingly? Comments may get deleted sooner or later